# Use an MVC Master Page in a WebForm page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, master-pages, webforms

I have an MVC application that I am creating that I have to integrate regular WebForms into the site. The WebForm pages will be using a ReportViewer control so I believe that won't work in a regular MVC view because ReportViewer uses ViewState, etc.

Is it possible for me to create a regular Web Form that uses an MVC View Master page? If so...is it possible to use the Html helper methods such as RenderPartial?

Comment: Don't see any answers on how to add the mvc master layout page to the webform page....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible for me to create a
>   regular Web Form that uses an MVC View
>   Master page?

I don't know for sure, but it might work, as long as it's just markup and doesn't use any MVC-specific features.

> If so...is it possible to use the Html
>   helper methods such as RenderPartial?

Nope. If you use it this way, the `Html` property will not be set automatically, and I don't know of any way to hack it in.

We began a project in WebForms and realized partway through that MVC suits our purposes far better, so until we can finish migrating away from WebForms we have to maintain two separate versions of each of our "portal" elements (tabs, logout buttons, etc.). It's a pain, but it's doable.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using RenderPartial you could call a MVC controller with ajax from your webforms app and use the html it returns.

```
  if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
   return View("someascx", model);
```